# stateDuration in angular-datatables is not recognized in dtOptions

Tags: datatables, angular-datatables

parameter stateDuration:0 is not recognized in dtOptions of dtElement?

```
  
impl. of dtOptions:
    this.dtOptions = {
      processing: false,
      serverSide: true,
      pagingType: localthis.tabelProperty.pagingType,
      lengthChange: false,
      info: false,
      *stateDuration:0,*
      responsive: true,
      autoWidth: false,
      ajax: {...}
      searching: true,
      dom: 'Brtipl',
      orderCellsTop: true,
      pageLength: localthis.tabelProperty.pageLength,
      stateSave: true,
      order: [],
      language: localthis.tabelProperty.language
      columns: [...]
}
```

parameter stateDuration shoud be visible in dtOptions of dtElement.